# Changing the value of the variable which a pointer holds the address of

Tags: c++

I have a very simple program:

```
int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int* b = &a;
    *b = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

I understand what a pointer does, it holds the address of a variable. So in my example, the pointer `b` holds the address of the variable `a`.

This is all fine.

My issue is with how dereferencing works. From my understanding, if I were to add a `cout` statement just before

```
*b = 100
```

such as:

```
cout << *b << endl;
```

Then the program should print `10`, as `*b` will get the value stored in the address that the pointer is holding.

My issue is, when I see the line:

```
*b = 100;
```

This just reads to me as "store 100 in the value stored in the address `b`", which would literally translate to 10 = 100. Now obviously this isn't what actually happens, what happens is that 100 will be stored in the address that the pointer is holding. My issue is that I can't understand why.

I understand that `b = 100` wouldn't make sense either, as you'd be trying to store the value 10 in the address of the variable `b`, which would replace the address of `a` being stored in `b`.

Maybe it's the choice of the asterisk symbol, but to me this just continuously reads as `10 = 100`, because seeing `*b` when `b` is a pointer to me means "get the value stored in the address that `b` is holding".

Could somebody explain dereferencing in C++, and why exactly `*b = 100` doesn't actually mean `10 = 100`?

Comment: Would an assignment `a = 100;` read as `10 = 100` or as an assignment?

Comment: `*b = 100` simply means put the value 100 where `b` points. As `b` points to `a`, `*b = 100` is the same as `a = 100`. In other words, then `b = &a` then `*b` works just like `a`. Both for reads and writes.

Comment: first make sure you understand `int x = 10;  x = 100;` Why is that not `10 = 100` ?   Once you understand that, the same applies to `*b = 100`

Comment: Your misunderstanding probably comes from here: `int* b = &a;`. This is 'equal' to `int* b; b = &a;` (and is not equal to `int* b; *b = &a;`), and it is confusing because assignment during declaration of a pointer looks like an assignment to a dereferenced pointer, but that is not what it is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
*b = 100
```

Can be read as "store the value 100 at the location that `b` points to".  And because `b` contains the address of `a`, the above is effectively the same as:

```
a = 100;
```

Formally speaking, the result of the dereference operator `*` is an **lvalue**, which basically means it is an object that can be assigned to just like the name of a variable by itself can be assigned to.

Comment: Your statement "store the value 100 at the location that b points to" makes sense, but this sounds more along the lines of dereferencing is the act of accessing the variable (who's address is stored in b). Instead of just returning the value stored in the memory address, which  b is holding

Comment: @Vyres Yes, that's another way of putting it.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could see the dereferencing as `*b` giving you an `int&` - a reference to the object it's pointing at.

Exemplified via a function returning an actual reference:

```
int& dereference(int* ptr) {
    return *ptr;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int* b = &a;

    std::cout << dereference(b) << '\n';    // prints 10

    dereference(b) = 100;                   // assigns 100

    std::cout << dereference(b) << '\n';    // prints 100
}
```